# Acces Google Api's for showing Movie Theatre timings based on current Lat and long

Tags: android, web-services, google-maps-api-3

I am currently developing a Places search nearby location so that ,currently I am getting list of Theatres near by location by using this API's

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?types=movie_theatre&location=12.987162,77.510551&radius=500&sensor=true&key="my_api_key".

So, What I want is that after selecting the theatre from the list. I need to show the Movie timings also . Please suggest me any api's to find the list of movie timings with name in JSON format

Thanks 
Anand

Answer (score 0):

1. Go here http://developer.tmsapi.com/io-docs
2. Choose OnConnect Data Delivery APIs
3. Movies Playing in Local Theatres